# jquery event added multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a fairly large javascript class that generates an complete ajax-generated application. In one version of the ajax page there are a number of dropdown menus. These menus can get created and destroyed at various points during the life cycle of the application.

This is the behaviour I see:

User opens page version 1: no dropdowns
User goes to page version 2: dropdowns added with jQuery onchange event. Work as intended.
User returns to version 1 of page, dropdowns removed.
User returns to version 2 of page, dropdowns added again (using same element IDs)
dropdowns will now have 'double' event handling, triggering the event for each onchange.

The behaviour I'm struggling with is as follows.

On the initial page load, I add an onchange event:

```
  function myClass(){
       //Initiate once for current and future elements.
   jQuery(document).on('change',".mydropdowns",
   function(e){
        self.submitDescriptionChange(this);
    }
   );
   }

   myClass.prototype.submitDescriptionChange = function (el){
        doSomeAjaxStuff();
   }
```

This works fine, except that each time the user goes to pages version 1 and returns to page version 2, the event gets multiplied. Very quickly you can end up with the event firing 20 times per change event, which in this case creates 20 ajax calls.

Logically, by using jQuery.off() I should be able to avoid this. But what happens instead is that the event is removed from both past and future elements, which means that when I recreate page version 2, the dropdowns won't work.

Every way I have tried this (and I've tried LOADS), I either end up with no event firing, or multiple events firing. I cannot seem to find a way to add/replace the elements whereby the event is only ever fired once.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

**UPDATED**

Yeah, so it turns out I misdiagnosed the problem. It actually came from repeatedly rebinding a 'hashchange' event, rather than rebinding the onchange event. Apologies for misdirection. Moving to bind() function to somewhere where it only executed once fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not want .off() to remove your events from other pages, I would suggest using namespaces for your events.  For example, something like this:

```
function myClass(pageno) {
    var pref_ev = 'mypage' + pageno + '.' + 'change';
    $(document).off(pref_ev).on(pref_ev, ".mydropdowns", function(e) {
        self.submitDescriptionChange(this);
    });
}
```

This way, each page will have its own "change" event such as "mypage1.change".  The event is still registered normally as a change event; the prefix namespace "mypage1" is used to only perform the .off() call on the right events.

Comment: Both good answers, apologies that I set the the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what plugin you are using for your dropdown menus but there should be a "destroy" method on that plugin. If you call that when removing the dropdowns that should work. Also, if you are only hiding the second page and not actually removing it from the DOM you dont have to re-invoke the plugin as the plugin will still be saved on the element.

Comment: Both good answers, apologies that I set the the wrong problem.